# Is this implication correct or not?

Tags: inequality

I want to understand this problem. If $ P = a > 0$ abd $Q = ab>0 \vee b \leq 0$, does $P$ implies $Q?$ How can I prove and understand  this is true or not?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your own question.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $R\iff (b>0).$

$P$ implies that $(ab>0\iff R).$

Now $Q\iff (ab>0\lor b\leq 0).$
 Therefore $P$ implies that $$Q\iff (R\lor b\leq 0)\iff (b>0\lor b\leq 0).$$ So $P$ implies that $Q$ is equivalent to something that is always true. So $P$ implies that $Q$ is true.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a > 0$. Then for $b$ either $b < 0$ or $b = 0$ or $b > 0$. Check that in all three cases, $Q$, holds

Comment: Thanks. Does this means that, as the disjunction is true for all values of $b$, the implication automatically holds?

Comment: @John To be precise one should say something like $\forall A \forall B (P \implies Q)$ which says that given any $a$, the implication $P \implies Q$ holds for any $b$, which is what this argument shows.